# Windows 7 SDK RC & Beta version

Tags: windows, windows-7, winapi

I've download Windows 7 SDK which was downloaded at the time of the beta release. Now I upgraded to RC and trying with some Direct2D samples. But I can't create the factory pointer using D2D1CreateFactory API. It's always returns NULL. Even the samples downloaded from MSDN is also not working well.

[There are some changes from Beta - RC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd756650(VS.85).aspx)

Is this because of the version mismatch of SDK?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I for one wouldn't use an old Windows SDK Beta. I recommend you to uninstall the beta and install a SDK that is for the OS you are running. In this case, [the Windows 7 SDK RC](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=6db1f17f-5f1e-4e54-a331-c32285cdde0c&displaylang=en).